# Properly close a GTK dialog window

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I built an application using Glade, Python3, Gtk3. When I open a dialog window and close it again, I receive the error:

```
  TypeError: on_aboutdialog_destroy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

My application looks like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  from gi.repository import Gtk
  from gi.repository import Gio
  import sys

  class Handler:
        #Main Window
        def on_mainwindow_destroy(self):
              print("destroy window")
              Gtk.main_quit()
        
        #Menu items
        def on_menuquit_activate(self, menuitem):
              print("quit from menu")
              Gtk.main_quit()

        def on_menuabout_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
              print("menu about activated")
              aboutdialog = builder.get_object("aboutdialog")
              aboutdialog.run()

        def on_aboutdialog_destroy(self):
              print("destroy about")
              aboutdialog.hide()
        

  builder = Gtk.Builder()
  builder.add_from_file("psn.glade")
  builder.connect_signals(Handler())

  window = builder.get_object("mainwindow")
  window.show_all()

  Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Hard to tell what exactly is going on without knowing what signals are connected, but have you tried doing what the error message says? Define `def on_aboutdialog_destroy(self, other_argument):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help at the official GTK-Forum. Closing works by doing this:

```
    self.ab = self.builder.get_object("aboutdialog")

    def on_aboutdialog_destroy(self, widget):
        self.ab.hide()
```